# Android Studio -> How to do a CLEAN without BUILD?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, if I do a clean in my Android project, it has a size of 30Mbytes, but in Android Studio, if I do a clean it has a size of 200Mbytes.

I also tried to do a clean from the console but it still has a weight of 100Mbytes. Note that I don't want to clean using a console command, i want to do it with Android Studio.

**How can I do a real clean in Android Studio to make the project size 30Mbytes?**

This is the official documentation for Android Studio but I can't find the solution: https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/

Answer (score -1):

You can't decide or estimate what the project size will be! Eclipse used to build differently without gradle files and all other stuff new in Android Studio.

So Android Studio builds differently than Eclipse and generates many more files, and hence more size. However size of .apk should remain same or almost same.